# Loading Managed C++ DLL from plain C++ Program via LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary

I'm trying to get a simple mixture between Managed C++ and plain C++ working. I'm using Visual Studio 2005 but keep hitting a problem. Here's my setup.

First, I have a simple DLL built from the code

```
#using "mscorlib.dll"

#include "windows.h"

__declspec(dllexport)
void sayHello()
{
    OutputDebugStringA( "Hello from managed code!" );
}
```

I compile this on the commandline to a DLL using

```
cl /CLR /LD dllcode.cpp
```

Next, I have a simple program consisting of nothing more than

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE lib = LoadLibrary( "dllcode.dll" );
    if ( !lib ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I build an application out of this using

```
cl loader.cpp
```

So I end up with `dllcode.dll` and `loader.exe` in the same directory. When trying to run `loader.exe`, I always get return code '1'. Looking up the error code yielded by `GetLastError()` shows that loading `dllcode.dll` failed due to `The specified module could not be found.`

Does anybody know why this could be? Does it have something to do with manifests which need to be embedded into `dllcode.dll` or so? I ran the depends program on dllcode.dll but it didn't yield any problems as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out why loading the Managed C++ DLL from my vanilla C++ program didn't work. Thanks once again to jdigital for pointing me to a useful tool:

The source of the error was that the MSVC8 runtime library was not found. I thought that the manifest which is generated when building via

```
cl /CLR /LD dllcode.cpp
```

is already embedded into the DLL. Apparently, it's not - so the loader failed to locate the appropriate MSVCR80.dll copy.

I fixed this problem by adding a second step to the DLL building routine:

```
cl /CLR /LD dllcode.cpp
mt -manifest dllcode.dll.manifest -outputresource:dllcode.dll;2
```

Hope this helps. Quite a beginner problem, I suspect...

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to see what LoadLibrary is trying to load.

Comment: Good idea; it seems that filemon was superseded by procmon. Using the latter, running the demo program yielded 1076 events. Unfortunately I couldn't see any errors in there - all the LoadImage calls succeeded, at least. Do you maybe have a suggestion what to look out for?

Comment: That's why I still use FileMon even though it has been superseded; procmon takes more work to set up and it's easier to make mistakes when configuring the filters.